# Cannot install PyProb

Tags: python, installation

I have installed Python 3.6.9 followed by Torch (version 1.5.1+cpu) and PyProj (version 1.9.5.1), but I cannot install PyProb. If I try

pip install pyprob

I get the error

Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Python 3.5+ is required.
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-Teq5Q6/pyprob/

Why do I get the message "Python 3.5+ is required" when I have Python 3.6.9?

Comment: which os you are using

Comment: can you check pip --version . It should point to your python 3.6.9 env

Answer (score 0):

Try this `pip install pyprob==1.0.0`
i use `python3.6.0` and `pip install pyprob` works for me.